# proxying an application that insists on running in a subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I'm currently trying to set up the [dynamic docker build](https://git.tt-rss.org/fox/ttrss-docker-compose/src/master/README.md) of ttrss. For various reasons, I have the docker container running in an lxd container, and for all intents and purposes, I have it running.

I currently have also a single ngnix server running in front of all my web-applications acting as a reverse proxy, with a wildcard letsencypt cert.

Proxying to the server works

tt-rss is set up to redirect connections to /tt-rss/, when I'd like it to be served from root. With my current set up, I'm getting sent to rss.foo.bar/tt-rss/ when I need it to go to rss.foo.bar, or get 404ed

My location block looks something like this at its base. I've tried adjusting the location from / to /tt-rss and the proxy pass block to include the subdomain

```
        location / {

                proxy_pass http://10.191.7.205:8280/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;

        }
```

How do I get this to work? I'd like to transparently go to foo.bar.ttrss rather than /tt-rss

I'd also like to get tt-rss, specifically to see SELF_URL_PATH  as rss.foo.bar. It currently detects it as https://rss.lupinenet.com/tt-rss/ which is part of my problem